# Google SignIn - Can I automatically login if I have an user with the same email?

Tags: security, google-signin

Im creating a feature where an user can use a google account to login.
A user already have an account with email and password.
Let's use email@gmail.com for example.
The user will click on sign in with Google and choose the account with email@gmail.com

My application will receive a google access token, then retrieve users details from google to validate.

Now my API already have access to the user's email and I'm sure that this user has access to email@gmail.

I'm thinking about to login right away the user.

**Does exists any drawback / security issue if I automatically login this user?**

If the user already have access to that email and dont remember the password, he could just click "forgot my password" and reset the password. So having access to users google account already give access to my application.

Comment: You want to use a google access token to allow access to your api?  Why would you want to do that?    Where do you want to reset the password your system or google?

Comment: Users already have an email + password account. If they need to reset they will receive an email with an access token from my application.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your system design.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo can you explain?